# Not able to break foreach loop

Tags: c#

I like to select the node where its text matches to some stirng values for this I wriiten one recursive method

```
private TreeNode GetSelectedNodes(TreeNode treeNode)
    {
        TreeNode result=new TreeNode();
        foreach (TreeNode node in treeNode.Nodes)
        {
            if (node.Text=="Child1")
            {
                result=node;
                break;
            }
            else
            if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                this.GetSelectedNodes(node);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

in above code one of node Text matches to "Child1" but its not returning node instead its again calling this.GetSelectedNodes(node); 
Please let me know what wrong with this code.

Comment: Have you tried running this with a debugger - putting a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line seeing if values are set as you expect?

Comment: Why are you completely ignoring the return value of `GetSelectedNodes()`? Also, you should probably be initializing `result` with `null` instead of a new `TreeNode()`. That way if `GetSelectedNodes()` returns `null`, you know to keep looking.

Comment: could this code, as posted, lead to an infinite loop?

Comment: @user1666620 Not unless there was a cycle in the tree, which would make it no longer a tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

trythis

```
private TreeNode GetSelectedNodes(TreeNode treeNode)
{            
    foreach (TreeNode node in treeNode.Nodes)
    {
        if (node.Text=="Child1")
        {                   
            return node;
        }
        else
        {
            if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                var result = this.GetSelectedNodes(node);
                if(result != null)
                {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: the problem seems to be that the code never validates to be true.

Comment: But same code is working in some other situation...May I know why its calling GetSelectedNodes(node) after break.??

Comment: In your code When it finds the expected node it will break the current loop but when it returns back to the previous recursive call(parent call) it continues the logic and does not use the found node in its child call branch, it just simply ignores the found node.
In new source code when a the node is found in a child branch it will not continue the search in parent loop it just returns the found node coming from the child call.

Comment: You missed this line in the else clause 
var result = this.GetSelectedNodes(node);
               if(result != null)
                   return result;

Answer (score -1):

Try this way. You return the node once found, and returns all the way up

```
private TreeNode GetSelectedNodes(TreeNode treeNode)
{
    TreeNode result=new TreeNode();
    foreach (TreeNode node in treeNode.Nodes)
    {
        if (node.Text=="Child1")
        {
            result=node;
            return result;
        }
        else if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            return this.GetSelectedNodes(node);
        }
    }
}
```